# JPA 2.0 - Does a db-lock-release awaiting thread definitely obtain the data after being released? Or just in case it still meets the initial criteria?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, db2, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I have a multi-threaded environment (clustered, so even multi-JVMs) with lots of threads quering a single db-table at the same time. All these threads are doing the exact same query, looking for an arbitrary entity with the state 'Available'. If a thread finds an 'Available' entity, it changes its state to 'Blocked' and dispatches it to the business-logic which does some subsequent work. This query for an 'Available' entity is a pessimistic-write-lock-query, thus the corresponding row in the db-table is locked for any other thread trying to access the same row simultaneously. All other threads will have to wait until the preceding thread releases the lock in the database.

Now my question is: does a thread that waits for a lock to be released on a certain entity receive this specific entity after the lock is released in any case? Even if the state of the entity does no longer meet the initial query criteria? In my scenario above, if a second thread queries for some entity with the state 'available' and finds an entity which is currently (write) locked by a first thread, does it mean the second thread will obtain this entity after its release in any case, even if the first thread changes its state to 'Blocked' in the meanwhile just before releasing the lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pessimistic locking:

In your scenario, query 1 gets a row that has 'Available' status and then updates the status to 'Blocked'.  If it *does not commit (or rollback)* this update, then when other queries searching for 'Available' rows try to read this row, they will wait –– they can't read the value of the row while it's locked.

If query 1 *commits* the update (i.e. the status is now 'Blocked'), then the other queries will **will not** have get the row.

If query 1 performs a *rollback* (the status of the row is reverted to 'Available'), then the other queries **will** get the row in their resultset.

To achieve the best concurrency in this situation, make sure the transaction performs this update as short as possible (i.e. separate the business logic that does the subsequent work into a separate transaction).  When the business logic completes, then make a decision on its success/failure and then update the row in question's status again.

Answer (score 0):

The question is DB-specific and has IMHO nothing to do with JPA. The answer is: the Thread2 will receive that specific entity (whose lock got held firstly by Thread1) ONLY if it still meet your search criteria (otherwise: what kind of database is that?: you ask for apples and it returns oranges).

Now if you want to test it yourself, open two console sessions to your DB and try it yourself.

PS: also consider the timeout when waiting for the lock to be released.

Answer (score 0):

> "*does it mean the second thread will obtain this entity after its
>   release in any case, even if the first thread changes its state (...)
>   in the meanwhile just before releasing the lock?*"

I would say it highly depends on the persistence provider and the underlying database as
***JPA specification says what to implement not how to implement***.

As described in *JPA 2.0 Specification*, chapter *3.4.3 Pessimistic Locking*:

> This specification does not define the mechanisms a persistence
>   provider uses to obtain database locks, and **a portable application
>   should not rely on how pessimistic locking is achieved on the
>   database**. For example, a persistence provider may use an underlying
>   database platform's `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statements to implement
>   pessimistic locking if that construct provides appropriate semantics,
>   or the provider may use an isolation level of *repeatable read*.

From the other hand using `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` guarantees *Repeatable Read* [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) that prevents from *non-repeatable reads* and *dirty reads* anomalies so if the underlying database concurrency control mechanisms provide comparable semantics (i.e. two-phase locking or multi-version concurrency control) this is sufficient in your particular case as OpenJPA provides pessimistic-write locking and DB2 provides its RS or RR isolation levels that meet the conditions.